# Blazor Server Periodic update of images using a timer

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Sorry for the rudimentary question.

An image is pasted and displayed on a web page created with Blazor Server.

I would like to update this displayed image on a regular basis. (For example, updated every second)

This image is stored in the location wwwroot / imageFiles with the name PreviewImage.bmp.

Specifically, I want to switch the image displayed on the web page to the replaced image when PreviewImage.bmp under this wwwroot / imageFiles is replaced.

For example, when I change PreviewImage.bmp that shows a dog to PreviewImage.bmp that shows a cat, I want to switch the image displayed on the web page.

I wondered if I could update the image using StateHasChanged (); with a timer, but this didn't work.

```
<img src="@previewImg" />

@code{
    
    private string previewImg = string.Empty;
    private Timer timer = new(1000);

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        previewImg = @"imageFiles/PreviewImage.bmp";

        timer.Elapsed += (sender, eventArgs) => OnTimerCallback();
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Start();            
    }

    private void OnTimerCallback()
    {    
        _ = InvokeAsync(() =>
       {    
         previewImg = @"imageFiles/PreviewImage.bmp";
         StateHasChanged();
       });
    }
 }
```

However, if you reload the entire page with the F5 key, the image will be updated.

Is there a way to achieve this image update?

I'm sorry that the content is very difficult to understand.

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting a junk query after the file name, something like:

```
previewImg = @"imageFiles/PreviewImage.bmp" + "?DummyId=" + DateTimeNow.Ticks;
```

Comment: Sorry for being late.
I tried immediately.

Wonderful.
This is working fine.

What does this code mean?
I searched for a junk query, but couldn't find a commentary.

Comment: This isn't unique to Blazor.  Browsers cache files for later use-- so if you've loaded a page with "XYZ.jpg," then the next time you load the page, it won't bother to download that file-- it will just use the one in the cache.  Adding a unique query lets the browser know that something may have changed and forces reload.  Be cautious with this, though-- if the image has not changed, you don't want to make the client keep re-downloading the same image file every time they come back to the page.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(_ =>
    {    
        InvokeAsync( async ()  =>
        {
            previewImg = @"imageFiles/PreviewImage.bmp";
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }, null, 0, 1000);

}
```